# Set global variable from async functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have the following.

```
var g = new Array() ; 

$.getJSON(google, function(data) {
  var i = 0 ; 
  $.each(data.items, function() {
    var obj = new res(i, this.title, this.snippet, this.formattedUrl, 0) ; 
    g.push(obj) ; 
    i=i+1 ;
  });
});
```

I need to be able to access the array outside the async function.

Comment: Please,format your code

Comment: If you are using the array outside of the async function, how will you know it is in the correct state?

Comment: If `g` is in the same scope as the `getJSON` call, then your anonymous function is a closure and already has access to `g`. If it's not in the same scope, you need to post a more detailed description of your code structure.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly answering the part about how to set up a global, one common way to do this is to create a namespace for your app, like

```
window.App = {}; // or just App = {};
```

and then to put global stuff in there

`App.g = [];`

And now you can access your namespace from anywhere.

Note you still need to be aware of when you might have outstanding requests modifying your global variables.

Comment: Wish I could up vote more than once.  This solves a problem I've had for years.

Answer (score 1):

you may opt to use the `.data()` which is simpler than global variables.

The way it works is that you set elements like this :

```
$('body').data('g', mydata);
```

anywhere, and retrieve it like this :

```
$('body').data('g');
```

Of course it can be on any element, not just `body`.